# Choosing strategy to handle response from asynchronous API call

Tags: web, asynchronous

There is a web application which does not have any own database, but communicates with remote through API. Performing a call to API takes some time and we do it asynchronously. The responsiveness of the application must be high from the user point of view.

Let's assume that the user is changing some data. To store the data we need to make a call. We start showing the new data right after making the call. But what can we do if the response of the call is unsuccessful? We need to restore the old values and show some kind of warning to the user. But the user may leave the page, where data were changed and see completely different page. What are general patterns to handle such situations?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net 4.5 you can do this using `async/await`. If your web client that you are calling provides an asynchronous API that returns a `Task` you can simply `await` the call inside a `try/catch` block. The `await` will cause the method to return immediately so the user will continue to observe the old data while it is executing. Once the we client call completes the method "resumes" after the `await` and you can update your data.

If the web client call causes an exception, the method will resume in the `catch` block and you can display an error to the user.

```
public async Task CallAPI()
{
    try
    {
        var client = ...
        await client.CallAPI();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // show warning message
    }
}
```

If your web client does not provide an asynchronous API you can achieve the equivalent with the Task Parallel Library.

```
public void CallAPI1()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
    {
        var client = ...
        client.CallAPI();
    }).ContinueWith( t => 
    {
        if(t.Exception != null)
        {   
           // display error
        }
        else
        {
            // update web page with 
        }
    },
    null,
    CancellationToken.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()); 
}
```

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) has more information on `async/await`. And [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) has some of the best practices to follow.